# Can I create multiple copies of Raspberry Pi SD card to avoid installation of OpenCV library and Python codes?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I want to use four Raspberry Pi and OpenCV applications. How can I copy/clone original SD card (installed OpenCV and Python programs) to other four SD card?

Answer (score 1):

On the Raspberry Pi desktop (launched by using startx in hard terminal) you can click the menu button (commonly on top left), click accessories, and then SD Card copier. From there you can copy your ENTIRE SD CARD to a flash drive, hard drive, or another SD card if you have an adapter. I use this to backup both partitions of my SD card.